# JAXB schema relation to classes/packages

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, schema

Looking for an answer on how best to organize our JAXB schema.  Seems like there are several possibilities, but being new to the scene I'd like to avoid a bad choice.  Possible organizations:

- One schema per Java package
- One schema per Java class
- One schema for all Java packages in project
- One schema for each other logical grouping of classes different than package

Is a schema per Java package the norm?  What are some of the consequences of each choice?  Any really bad ones, or does it just not matter much?  Is one schema per class overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We designed JAXB so that:

- a package corresponds to an XML Schema (i.e. package level `@XmlSchema` annotation)
- a class corresponds to a complex type (i.e. class level `@XmlType` annotation)
- a property corresponds to an attribute or element (i.e property level `@XmlAttibute` and `@XmlElement` annotations)

Comment: Thanks, It would be nice if that was spelled out clearly in one of the JAXB tutorials or guides I've been skimming over lately, maybe I just missed it.